# Breadth First Search in matrix from source to destination

Tags: python, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have a numpy 2d Matrix that look like this :

```
[
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' 'c' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '' 't' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' 'c' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' 'm' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
]
Source : 't'
destination : 'm'
```

But the move-set of the 't' emulates the moves of a knight from the game of Chess.

[image: check the image]

Blue is 't' and pink points are it's next moves. How can i apply Breadth first search or Depth First search to find next best move for 't' toward 'm'

Comment: you can check this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-steps-reach-target-knight/ ( it uses BFS )

Comment: thanks for the link , let me try it out

Comment: @GaneshSwamypillai it's the minimum steps to reach destination but i want to get next possible move for my 't'